# Created a timer using useRef to store value but value is not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the react documentation, it mentions that using useRef can be used to store values which you want to update but do not want to re-render the page. I tried creating a timer which uses setInterval to increment the ref, but although this ref is updating within setInterval function, it does not update in the react component. Why is that the case?

Most online material suggest storing this data in state for creating a timer. However, I do not want the entire component to re-rerender when the timer updates.

I have also tried creating a timer in a seperate component and rendering it in the parent component. Although this method does not cause the parent component to re-render whenever the timer updates, i need the interval function to be in the parent component and therefore i do not want to create a seperate timer component with its own setinterval() function

```
const Timer = () => {
  const timerRef = useRef<number>(0); 

  useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            timerRef.current += 1
        }, 1000) 
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }

   return (
     <p> Timer: {timerRef.current} </p>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried creating a timer which uses setInterval to increment the ref, but although this ref is updating within setInterval function, it does not update in the react component. Why is that the case?

Such is the nature of refs in React!

> useRef is a React Hook that lets you reference **a value that’s not needed for rendering.**

— [React Docs: useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef)

The ref values is being updated by the timer but it won’t be displayed in the UI because no rerender is scheduled by updating the ref. Ref values should only be read in event handlers or effects and **never** in render (ie in JSX). State should be used for data that changes over time and is displayed in the UI.

> Do not write or read ref.current during rendering. [...] **If you have to read or write something during rendering, use state instead.**

— [React docs - useRef Pitfall](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef)

> However, I do not want the entire component to re-rerender when the timer updates.

If you need to display the timer value in the UI, there's no way around updating the component. Re-rendering is most likely is faster than you'd expect.

```js
const Timer = () => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((timer) => timer + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return <p> Timer: {timer} </p>;
};
```

Also note the empty dependency list of `useEffect`.

And I'd recommended reading this blogpost [Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)
 for a better understanding of React hooks.

Comment: Wow, awesome! Learned new thing ;) Thanks for introducing `useState` to us.

Comment: hi jules thanks for the reply! For my parent component unfortunetely re-rendering every second causes one of my charts to flicker every second. Since it is necessary to use render, what would be a way to prevent that chart from re-rendering? Would use Memo be the right solution?

Comment: You can try to split the component into parts (ie JSX) that changes with the timer state and parts that don't change. Lift the JSX that doesn't change with timer state up where it's rerended less often, pass it down using `children`. (Recommened post [Before You Memo](https://overreacted.io/before-you-memo/). Applying `React.useMemo` to values may help. `React.memo` on child components of the chart might also help but you'd need to make sure all the props passed to the memoized component do not change. I'd recommend running a profile to find the bottleneck.